# What is jQuery like syntax doing in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I was just going through some Vue.js code [HERE](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/develop/website/client/components/tasks/task.vue#L23) and came across the following line of code:

```
.svg-icon.streak(v-html="icons.streak", v-b-tooltip.hover.bottom="$t('streakCounter')")
```

There is this jQuery like syntax $t() and i don't quite understand it , what exactly is this function doing ? where is it coming from ? i see no such function being `imported` ?

Can somebody explain what this jQuery like syntax is doing ?

Comment: It looks like it's passing an element for the tooltip attribute to hover under

Comment: @DerekPollard yeah ! but where is this function `$t()` coming from and what is it's purpose as you can see , its everywhere used in the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from the i18n : https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/develop/website/client/libs/i18n.js

```
// Vue plugin to globally expose a '$t' method that calls common/i18n.t.
// Can be anywhere inside vue as 'this.$t' or '$t' in templates.
```

And you can find `streakCounter` here : https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/1135ab946e11300c2199c14cb5451f7370ed0b28/website/common/locales/en/tasks.json#L57 (and in other translation file for different languages)